# adding the text box values using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a Grid view which contains various text boxes. I need to add all the text box values and display the result in a separate Text Box. I need to use java script for this.
Please help me out.

Comment: You need to have an attempt so far, show us what code you've got and which bit you had difficulty with.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First of all, please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times. Show your work and tell people what have you tried. People can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your grid is basically a table on client side, so get access to table using your grid id and then loop through its rows to get your textbox values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by:

> I have a Grid view which contains various text boxes. I need to add
>   all the text box values and display the result in a separate Text Box.

When you utilize a *Grid View* it should actually populate your storage of data in a coherent manner. Unless your remark indicates rather then a traditional *Grid View* your utilizing *textboxes* instead.

You may want to look at *Knockout*.  This particular *Java Script* library is quite powerful and dynamic- An example would be like so:

*The Markup:*

```
<div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

<button data-bind='click: addItem'>
    Add item
</button>

<button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
    Sort by name
</button>

<button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
       Jump to first page
</button>
```

*The script:*

```
var initialData = [
    { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
    { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
    { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
    { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.addItem = function() {
        this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
    };

    this.sortByName = function() {
        this.items.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
        });
    };

    this.jumpToFirstPage = function() {
        this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
    };

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
            { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
        ],
        pageSize: 4
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
```

[Here is a link to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/).

This is one of the wonderful documentations directly from *Knockouts* page which can be found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html).  Anyways, hopefully this helps you-  You can actually utilize several aspects of this project to accommodate your desired goal.  The only difference will be the implementation of *textboxes* which I'm assuming are to modify the internal grid data.  Hopefully this points you in a good direction.

Answer (score 0):

try this

mark up:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>text box 1</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text box 2</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text box 3</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>text box 4</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>text box 5</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>text box Final</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="textbox"  value="value5" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="final"  />
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var getp = document.getElementsByClassName('textbox');
   var temp = "";
   for(i=0;i<getp.length;i++)
     {
       temp +=getp[i].value+" ";
     }
   document.getElementById('final').value = temp
</script>
```